# How to access the value of a promise

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I have tried displaying a Promise
Which looks like this

```
 ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: 
                        Array(0)}
          __zone_symbol__state:true
          __zone_symbol__value:3
          __proto__:Object
```

I want to use the value of __zone_symbol__vaklue:3
How do i access it??

Comment: Using its then() method. Use google, it's your friend. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: last=this._employeeService.
    lastEmployeeID().then(result=>result.data);
Will this work??
Searched intensively on Google ; no useful search result